# How to enable debugging of stored procedures in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging

Ok, this is driving me nuts.

I've done just about everything I can to enable step through debugging of stored procedures of a sql server 2005 database.

http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2007/05/debugging-stored-procedures-debug.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zefbf0t6(vs.71).aspx

My currents setup:

1. visual studio 2008 SP1
2. SQL server 2005 express database (yes you can debug on this)
3. DEV database on my localmachine with "root" login as sysadmin

All I want to do is right click on a stored proc in my server explorer in VS 2008 and see "step into stored procedure". I've done all I can and I can't see that.
I'm just trying to access a local database on my local machine, I've created an account

Comment: I've got the Pro version. I know it _should_ be there but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What edition of VS2008 are you running?  I just checked on Pro and Team System, and I get that option on both; I also have C# Express, and it doesn't give this option.  (I don't have Standard, so can't check that one...)

[edit] From the second link you provided (MSDN), on the right-hand side there's a link for VS2008 that indicates it only applies to Pro and Team.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your connection in Server Explorer and right click on that, and select
`Allow SQL/CLR Debugging`

Comment: This is supported in only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

To do sql debugging in managed code  or visual studio, visual studio should be configured to enable sql server deubugging. this link helps you with direct solution http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984533(v=vs.71).aspx but the edition of the visual studio should be considered.Pls refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165038(v=vs.80).aspx.

Apparently, You might not get Debug tab though the versions are pro/team and if its a web application project. To make it work, you need to select web tab-->scroll the screen very down-->Get 3 options as in below image.

[image: View The Image For Help]